# Install all NodeJS modules

Tags: webstorm

Inside my WebStorm NodeJS project I have a `package.json` with this content:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "main": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./app-compiled.js"
  },
  "dependencies" : {
    "gulp" : "latest",
    "body-parser" : "latest"

  }
}
```

When I do `npm install` in root directory of the project, several dozen of modules get installed (see: http://take.ms/Iavqh), while I expect only 2 modules to get installed.

[image]

1. Why are all these modules get installed? What should I do in order for just 2 modules to get installed?
2. `npm install` creates a `node_modules` folder that has a "library root" sign. What does it mean?

Comment: Those must be packages used by your `gulp` and `body-parser` modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these are dependancies of gulp. If you open gulp file you will see lot of var someName = require(''); This are called dependancies. npm install is an recursive installation.